# Prove a simple relation involving the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n x)}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the following identity holds:

$$ 16f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + 16f\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)= 27 f(\alpha) -9 f(2\alpha) + f(3\alpha)$$

where $\alpha = 2\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: Very interesting. Where did you find such identity?

Comment: Is this even true? I get $\approx 16$ on the left and $\approx 24$ on the right.

Comment: Agree with @GeorgeV.Williams: the left-hand side is $15.97$ and the right-hand side is $24.09$.

Comment: There was a typo on the l.h.s. of the identity which I just corrected

Comment: I think a the LHS should be $$16\left(f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+f\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\right),$$ in order that both sides are $\approx 24.092$.

Comment: I think such identity can be derived from formula 3.2 (section 3, the Bloch-Wigner function) in the Don Zagier survey about the dilogarithm function, maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0hg/dilog.pdf .

Comment: Moreover, it is just identity (27) in the following Borwein paper: arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9811173